# Conditional compilation in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I would like to 'turn off' the compiler for a section of my code.  I do not want to use comments to 'hide' the code from the compiler because there are a lot of `/*...*/` comments embedded in this section.  I would guess that there is a common way to use compiler directives or #defines or something to control the compilation.  In fact my desire to suppress compilation is not dependent on a condition like the SDK or the platform, I would just like to turn it off.  How does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick fix is to wrap that section of code with

```
#if 0
…
#endif
```

where 0 means false. To enable it again,

```
#if 1
…
#endif
```

Another option is to define a macro (Project Info -> Build -> Preprocessor macros) and define it when you want to disable that code, and undefine it when you want to enable that code. For instance,

```
#ifndef IGNORE_THIS_SECTION
…
#endif
```

You can achieve a similar, ‘inverse’ effect by using `#ifdef` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a preprocessor flag that is checked at compile time. I use this for multiple targets.

Step 3 Writing Preprocessor Codes, of this tutorial for creating multiple targets:

http://just2us.com/2009/07/tutorial-creating-multiple-targets-for-xcode-iphone-projects/

tells you how to create a flag and use the #if conditional compile.